# I need a recursive query to get a calculated field in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm not sure what the best approach is to get the result I'm looking for.  In an oracle 10g database I'm trying to query all the users and produce a calculated field for each row that has their supervisor IF their supervisor type is U.  If it is not I need to walk up the tree until I find one that is. This query might need to recurse up multiple levels.

So for an Employee table like this:

```
Employee Table
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+
| empno | empgroup |     user     | supervisor_no |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|     1 | E        | Joe Schmo    |             4 |
|     2 | E        | Mark Marin   |             3 |
|     3 | U        | Reed Patter  |             7 |
|     4 | E        | Martin Price |             7 |
|     7 | U        | Mary Wengert |               |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+
```

I'd like to see results like this where manager_no would be the calculated field

```
Results
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| empno | empgroup |     user     | supervisor_no | Manager_No |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+
|     1 | E        | Joe Schmo    |             4 |          7 |
|     2 | E        | Mark Marin   |             3 |          3 |
|     3 | U        | Reed Patter  |             7 |          7 |
|     4 | E        | Martin Price |             7 |          7 |
|     7 | U        | Mary Wengert |               |            |
+-------+----------+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

Ok so I have been asked what I have tried.  I am not saying this is the way it has to be done so if someone has a better suggestion I'm all ears but this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I envisioned two parts.  The main query that gets all my results

```
select em.empno, em.empgroup, em.user, em.supervisor, (my subquery) as manager_no
from employee em
```

**Query**:

```
select * from employee em
connect by prior supervisor_no = empno
start with empno = 1
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| EMPNO | EMPGROUP |     USERNAME | SUPERVISOR_NO |
---------------------------------------------------
|     1 |        E |    Joe Schmo |             4 |
|     4 |        E | Martin Price |             7 |
|     7 |        U | Mary Wengert |        (null) |
```

Ok, I found a way to filter on the group that might work but not sure if this is the most efficient route to go.

```
SELECT empno FROM (
SELECT empno FROM employee em
CONNECT BY PRIOR supervisor_no = empno
START WITH empno = 1 
order by level) d
WHERE d.empgroup = 'U' and rownum =1
```

I also created a fiddle if that helps.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8805/4

Comment: Fair question.  I don't know for sure if that's what I need but I do need to keep querying each person's supervisor until I get the one that meets my criteria.  I will add some more information to the question on what I have tried as soon as I can.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for your SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your question became quite a challenge to me, but I didn't give up and got this using only sql and built-in functions (shouldn't work slowly, and quite indexable is needed):

```
select distinct 
  empno, 
  empgroup, 
  username, 
  supervisor_no, 
  manager_no 
from (
  select 
            e.*, 
            decode(
        instr(
            sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
            'U/', 
            -1
        ), 
        0, 
        null, 
        substr(
            sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/'), 
            instr(
                sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/'), 
                '/',
                1, 
                length(
                    substr(
                        sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                        1, 
                        instr(
                            sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                            'U/', 
                            -1
                        )
                    )
                ) - length(
                    replace(
                        substr(
                            sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                            1, 
                            instr(
                                sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                'U/', 
                                -1
                            )
                        ), 
                        '/'
                    )
                )
            ) + 1, 
            instr(
                sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/'), 
                '/',
                1, 
                length(
                    substr(
                        sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                        1, 
                        instr(
                            sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                            'U/', 
                            -1
                        )
                    )
                ) - length(
                    replace(
                        substr(
                            sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                            1, 
                            instr(
                                sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                'U/', 
                                -1
                            )
                                            ), 
                                                '/'
                                        )
                                ) + 1
                        ) - instr(
                                sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/'), 
                                '/',
                                1, 
                                length(
                                        substr(
                                                sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                                1, 
                                                instr(
                                                        sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                                        'U/', 
                                                        -1
                                                )
                                        )
                                ) - length(
                                        replace(
                                                substr(
                                                        sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                                        1, 
                                                        instr(
                                                                sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/'), 
                                                                'U/', 
                                                                -1
                                                        )
                                                ), 
                                                '/'
                                        )
                                )
                        ) - 1
                )
        ) manager_no 
    from employee e
  connect by prior empno = supervisor_no
) 
where manager_no is not null or supervisor_no is null
order by empno;
```

The SQL Fiddle for the query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8805/27/0

**UPDATE:**
When I got up in the morning, I realized that everything can be done much easier and the query became more readable, here you go:

```
select   
  empno, 
  empgroup, 
  username, 
  supervisor_no, 
  null manager_no 
from 
  employee
where 
  supervisor_no is null 
union all
select   
  empno, 
  empgroup, 
  username, 
  supervisor_no, 
  substr(ep, 2, instr(ep, '/', 2)-2) manager_no 
from (
  select 
    sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/') gp,
    sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/') ep,
    e.*
  from employee e
  connect by prior empno = supervisor_no
  ) e
where 
  substr(gp, 1, 3) = '/U/' 
  and (length(gp) - length(replace(gp, 'U/'))) = length('U/')
order by empno;
```

And it works! As well as the query above. SQL Fiddle for it: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8805/54/0

Enjoy!

Comment: Yahoo, done for every name of the needed group and any length of ID of an employee. What a captivating task! Tried to format it properly for you in order to undestand what it means. Now back to work..

Comment: Do you think you could summarize what this is doing? I'm having a hard time reading this but the results look good.

Comment: The trick is to use the function `sys_connect_by_path`, which provide you with the path from the root to the node as string. So, after getting it, I analyze the string given for `sys_connect_by_path(empgroup, '/')` on which level I firstly come across 'U/' (it means the nearest parent which is not 'E') and then try to extract necessary ID from the same level in `sys_connect_by_path(empno, '/')`. So, mostly working with strings.

Comment: I've added one more query which came to my mind this morning, it's quite easier, the trick is the same, but usage of it is "a bit" wiser)

Comment: Thank you for explaining it, that makes way more sense now. I will try to test this out asap

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a recursive function that gets a user's 'U' type supervisor?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_U_SUPERVISOR(employee_no INT)
RETURN INT IS
    supervisor_empno INT;
    supervisor_group VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
    SELECT empno, empgroup
    INTO supervisor_empno, supervisor_group
    FROM employee
    WHERE employee.empno = (SELECT supervisor_no FROM employee WHERE empno = employee_no);

    IF 'U' = supervisor_group
    THEN
        RETURN supervisor_empno;
    ELSE
        RETURN GET_U_SUPERVISOR(supervisor_empno);
    END IF;
END GET_U_SUPERVISOR;
/
```

Then:

```
SELECT empno, empgroup, username, supervisor_no, GET_U_SUPERVISOR(empno)
FROM employee;
```

A SQL Fiddle back at you: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7540/1/0

I can't promise any performance on that, though, if it's a large table. It's recursive and would be called on a per row basis.

Comment: oh, gosh, recursively working pl/sql function.. for such a task, just a resource-killer, dude!

Comment: I do appreciate you taking the time for this but I would like to avoid creating custom functions as I don't have rights to on the db I'm working with.

Comment: Oh, Oracle. How I loathe thine permissions. @ZZa I never promised high performance. I even warned about it. Sometimes, you don't need high performance, though. The OP gave us no indication about the size of the data. I just tried to give a working solution. I find the downvote uncalled for.

Comment: Yah I am sorry I should have specified my limitation regarding creating custom functions.  I do really appreciate the help either way.

Answer (score -1):

I used WITH recursive, [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8bb892/17/0),

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(NO INT, EMP_GROUP VARCHAR2(1), EUSER VARCHAR2(30), SUPERVISOR_NO INT);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(1, 'E', 'JOE SCHMO', 4);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(2, 'E', 'Mark Marin', 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(3, 'U', 'Reed Patter', 7);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(4, 'E', 'Martin Price ', 7);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(NO, EMP_GROUP, EUSER) VALUES(7, 'U', 'Mary Wengert');
WITH  A(EMPLOYEE, MANAGER) AS 
(
  SELECT NO AS EMPLOYEE, SUPERVISOR_NO AS MANAGER FROM EMPLOYEE
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A.EMPLOYEE, E.SUPERVISOR_NO AS MANAGER
  FROM A, EMPLOYEE E
  WHERE A.MANAGER = E.NO
  AND E.SUPERVISOR_NO IS NOT NULL
)

SELECT * FROM A
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Your query results in two extra rows with incorrect results. On your SQL Fiddle, the first row maps employee `1` to supervisor `4` (who is not a `'U'` manager), and the last row maps employee `2` to supervisor `7` (who is not the lowest level `'U'` type manager that `2` is under).

Comment: Yeah correct. But I used WITH recursive to demonstrate we can find out immidiate supervisors.